# Use of reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, reinterpret-cast

Is there anything wrong with the following code? In particular I'm interested in the use of `reinterpret_cast`.

```
class Base1
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class Base2
{
public:
    virtual void bar(){}
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{
};

int main()
{
    Base1* instance1 = new Derived();
    instance1->foo();

    Base2* instance2 = reinterpret_cast<Base2*>(instance1);
    instance2->bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the `Base2` inheritance non-`public` on purpose?

Comment: @zenith No. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you can't cast between `Base2` and `Derived`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/860339/3425536

Comment: But it compiles and appears to run OK.

Comment: @ksl just because something compiles does not make it correct.

Comment: Well you're using `reinterpret_cast`, so obviously. Probably undefined behavior though.

Comment: I've corrected Derived to inherit publicly from Base2.

Comment: Can you cast `instance1` to `Derived*` instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` doesn't know how to handle casting between siblings (for example in vtable implementations it won't fix up the `this` pointer) so it will definitely not work. Note that it may *appear* to do what you expect. You'll want to use `dynamic_cast` in this case, or alternately `static_cast` to derived and use the implicit conversion to `base2`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a simple `dynamic_cast` to `Derived*` would be preferred:

```
Base2* instance2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(instance1);
```

(Or `static_cast` if you *know* that `*instance1` is really a `Derived`, and you don't want the dynamic dispatch overhead. Not recommended though.)

Comment: @ksl Cast to `Derived*`.